# Execute sql in grails job groovy file to configure value for cron trigger

Tags: grails, groovy, cron, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to assign a property for cronExpression value as below class

```
RecursiveNotificationJob {
    def reminderService;
    def grailsApplication
    String cronValue = "0 0 8 * * ?"

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'recursiveNotificationTrigger', cronExpression: cronValue
    }

    def execute() {
        println new Date().toString() +" Recursive Notification Job is working";
        reminderService.execute();
    }

}
```

In fact I would like to have the cronExpression value to be configured and called from a table as my example below

```
class RecursiveNotificationJob {
    def reminderService;
    def grailsApplication
    String cronValue = Parameter.executeQuery("select value from Parameter where name='RecursiveNotification'");

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'recursiveNotificationTrigger', cronExpression: cronValue
    }

    def execute() {
        println new Date().toString() +" Recursive Notification Job is working";
        reminderService.execute();
    }

}
```

Both of them doesn't work seem. Appreciate any idea or suggestion how this can be done in proper way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't fetch the cron expression from database in static block as the Job Classes are loaded before the gorm is initiated. We ran into similar usecase where the cronExpression had to be read from database. Here is how we solved it.

Don't define the triggers at Job Level, Means that the job will not be scheduled by default.

```
RecursiveNotificationJob {
    def reminderService;
    def grailsApplication

    def execute() {
        println new Date().toString() +" Recursive Notification Job is working";
        reminderService.execute();
    }
}
```

Schedule the Job Manually in Bootstrap.groovy.

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder
import org.quartz.Trigger
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder

class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        this.scheduleJob();        
    }

    def destroy = {
    }

    def scheduleJob() {
        def triggerName = "RecursiveNotificationTrigger", 
            triggerGroup = "RecursiveNotification",
            cronExpression = Parameter.executeQuery("select value from Parameter where name='RecursiveNotification'");


        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
            .withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
            .build();


        RecursiveNotificationJob.schedule(trigger)
    }
}
```

Comment: I having error as groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TriggerBuilder for class: BootStrap.
May I know which library this Trigger is called from?

Comment: You need to import them ! Updated the code with the Imports..Just incase. And i'm assuming you are on quartz version is > 2.0

Comment: I had error " Error executing bootstraps: No such property: RecursiveNotificationJob for class: BootStrap".. I tried import that job class into here but I had error as well.

Comment: Where is your Job File ? Can you provide the full path ?

Comment: yes. the path is grails-app\jobs\org\fsl\RecursiveNotificationJob.groovy

Comment: Have you tried importing "org.fsl.RecursiveNotificationJob" in Bootstrap.groovy ? If you are using GGTS, it will show import error which can be ignored. You should be able to run the app.

Which version of Grails are you on ? I'm using 2.3.7